# js - multiple if statements, if condition isnt met the following if statements are not checked

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have the following if statements, but if the first condition is not met the following if statements are not checked. I need them all to be checked.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   if(document.getElementById('firstname').value = "unsolicited"){document.getElementById('firstname').value = "";}
   if(document.getElementById('mobile').value = "unsolicited"){document.getElementById('mobile').value = "";}
   if(document.getElementById('email').value = "unsolicited@gmail.com"){document.getElementById('email').value = "";}
}, false);
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: use comparison operator `==` or `===`. Instead of assignment operator `=`

Comment: Really unclear what you are asking.... but `=` is assignment. A good linter on your IDE will point out that typo

Comment: @epascarello so would a basic understanding of the language. A crutch is always a crutch, and telling someone to use one when they haven't learned to use their legs isn't good advice in my opinion.

Comment: @JDunken I have been coding for 22+ years, sometimes we fat finger stuff and good to have a tool that points it out. I wish I had a linter when I started, I might have more hair on my head. Instead I had alerts to debug. lol

Comment: Unfortunately using == or === didnt work ..im afraid to say. Thanks so much for trying though. Sorry if my original question wasnt clear. Its basically that it doesnt check any if statements that follow any if statement that isnt met. I hope that makes more sense!?

Comment: @epascarello I've been coding for 15+, so I understand that, and I agree that a linter can be useful. But this question shows a clear lack of understanding of the language. A linter at this point in op's coding education removes the need to reason about their mistakes. That reasoning would build a greater understanding; something, you surely notice, quite a few are lacking as you visit this site. OP, I'm not trying to be disparaging, keep working on it, keep editing your question as you do, you will find a solution.

Comment: Using == or === makes every if statement fail. As this is so simple, im surprised noone has answered the question correctly yet! Heres a fiddle if that helps? https://jsfiddle.net/8esvcz5n/1/

Answer (score 3):

Actually you assign a value which you like to check.

You could store the wanted `id` for checking in an array along with the unwanted value and iterate the array and replace the value with an empty string.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    [['firstname', 'unsolicited'], ['mobile', 'unsolicited'], ['email', 'unsolicited@gmail.com']]
        .forEach(([id, value]) => {
            const element = document.getElementById(id);
            if (!element) return;
            if (element.value === value) element.value = '';
        });
}, false);
```

```html
<input placeholder="first name" id="firstname" name="form[firstname]" type="text" value="unsolicited">
<input placeholder="mobile" id="mobile" name="form[mobile]" type="text" value="unsolicited">
<input placeholder="email" id="email" name="form[email]" type="text" value="unsolicited@gmail.com">
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that Nina! Very kind, although unfortunetly it isnt working for me at this stage.

Comment: The fields with unsolicited as their value remain with unsolicited as their value.

Comment: maybe the event is wrong. mabe you the event on change or submit. actually it looks like it is called on load.

Comment: yes it is on load. but my original code was working fine (except for it stopped after an if condition wasnt met).

Comment: @NinaScholz add check for null on element, or nullpointer might arise

Comment: @NinaScholz just to say thanks again and I was just wondering if you had any idea why this wasnt working.. ive setup a fiddle and isnt working their either im afraid to say.. your help on this would be much appreciated https://jsfiddle.net/8esvcz5n/1/

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks again really appreciate this, although I have to say Im perplexed as to why this isnt working on the fiddle or on my site, although I can see the example here is working fine ..heres the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/13tp72mc/

Comment: i have no idea. but it is striking.